# It's showing \n when printing the list

Tags: python, list, csv, file-handling

The output:

```
{'name': 'Peter', 'surname': ' Abdilla', 'DOB': ' 22/02/1986', 'mobileNo': '79811526', 'locality': ' Zabbar\n'}
{'name': 'John', 'surname': ' Borg', 'DOB': ' 12/04/1982', 'mobileNo': '99887654', 'locality': ' Paola\n'}
```

The expected output is supposed to be:

```
{'name': 'Peter', 'surname': ' Abdilla', 'DOB': ' 22/02/1986', 'mobileNo': '79811526', 'locality': ' Zabbar'}
{'name': 'John', 'surname': ' Borg', 'DOB': ' 12/04/1982', 'mobileNo': '99887654', 'locality': ' Paola'}
```

Comment: Try this: `value = x.rstrip('\n').split(',')`

Comment: ```contact = dict(tuple(zip(keys,value.strip('\n'))))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each line in CSV has an endLine character which is `'\n'`, so when you try to read the contents of the csv file line by line, '\n' will also be in the string.

So, we just need to replace the `'\n'` with an empty string.

To fix this, use the python's string `replace()` function.

```
while True:
    x = file.readline()
    x = x.replace('\n', '')
    if x == '':
        break
    else:
        value = x.split(',')
        contact = dict(tuple(zip(keys,value)))
        filename.append(contact)
```